# How to specify order of running in multimodules maven webapp?

Tags: java, maven, websphere, ear

I have a multi-modules application which build on maven. In one of the modules i have some initialization logic (with ServletContextListener) which should be execute before other modules. My application server is WebSphere. How can i configure strict order of execution for my modules (maybe on application's level or maybe on Websphere's level)?.

UPD:i tried to add **initializeInOrder** property, but it does not work for me (order does not change).
UUPD:There is only one solution which i found. **Starting weight** configuration helps me. It is a WebSphere configuration for application with multiple modules. Module with lower weight should be execute earlier. But i want to solve this problem on ear's level.

Comment: Are you creating an EAR file?

Comment: @khmarbaise yes, i am

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [initializeInOrder](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/generate-application-xml-mojo.html#initializeInOrder) element of ear:generate-application-xml plugin?

Comment: Yes, see 'UPD' section.

Comment: then the application.xml in ear contains the element <initialize-in-order>true</initialize-in-order> right? and WAS server (version?) doesn't interpret this during the start?